# Load an image into a ListView without an ImageList?

Tags: c, winapi

Is there a way to load an image into a ListView without using an ImageList, for example just load an HBITMAP directly into a specific item in the ListView without placing it first into an ImageList.

Comment: I don't think so, unfortunately.

Comment: Define "load an image into a list view".

Comment: @David Heffernan Like put an image to (row 2, column 4).

Comment: Have you tried custom draw?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to [custom-draw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761817(v=vs.85).aspx) the list items.  You need to handle the list view's [NM_CUSTOMDRAW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774865(v=vs.85).aspx) notification. Then you can draw the items any way you want.